# Deleting Facebook Page inbox messages via the graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, message

Is there currently a way to 'delete' inbox messages for Facebook pages using the API?

I understand that deleting an inbox message on facebook.com only removes it from your inbox, and doesn't entirely remove the message.  Is there a call that provides this same functionality using the API?

I've tried DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/m_id.123456789?access_token={page_access_token} to no avail (OAuthException (#3) Unknown method)

Comment: Same question as http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7607341/deleteing-facebook-messages-via-facebook-api, but this one's over a year old, any updates to the API since then that might have enabled this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete a inbox message using the API currently. As the permission states (`read_mailbox`), the API only provides read-only access to messages.